# How to switch language for one element of iOS-App?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**My question:**
How to switch language for one element of iOS-App ?

I have app with different languages locale there 
function of switch locale (language) work fine.

but I can't to understand how to make function for my special element (button) that switched only part of my app to another language.
So I can't to find any information about right solution.

Any one please help

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please update your question with some relevant code and some specific information about what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: @rmaddy I think he is looking for a *per view* `Locale` property. But he sure could improve his wording a little ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think **UIKit** provides such a fine grained localization support (i.e., *language per view*). The current locale is an application wide setting, made available by `Locale.current`.

You may need to track such settings yourself and configure the desired views accordingly.